# Masstransit Consumer Unit Test sometimes has empty messages, with rabbit Mq backend it works

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm using xunit unit tests to test the MassTransit consumers, in most cases it works but in some cases the "context.message" in the consumer is filled with an object containing empty properties. (all string are null, guid is 000-0000.. etc.) The unit tests compared between running and not running tests looks identical.

a) Command (Message)

```
public record UpdateKontakteintragCommand : ApplicationCommandRequest
{
    public string Bemerkung { get; init; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // TODO: Fallaktenzuordnungsdatum
}
```

b) Unit Test:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task UpdateKontakteintrag_Complete_AcceptedMessage()
    {
        var consumer = harness.Consumer(() => new UpdateKontakteintragCommandConsumer(kontakteintragRep));

        await harness.Start();

        try
        {
            var requestClient = await harness.ConnectRequestClient<UpdateKontakteintragCommand>();

            var command = new UpdateKontakteintragCommand { Id = nonDeletedGuid, Bemerkung = "abc", };

            await requestClient.GetResponse<AcceptedResponse, FaultedResponse>(command);

            Assert.True(consumer.Consumed.Select<UpdateKontakteintragCommand>().Any());
            Assert.True(harness.Sent.Select<AcceptedResponse>().Any());
        }
        finally
        {
            await harness.Stop();
        }
    }
```

c) Consumer

```
public class UpdateKontakteintragCommandConsumer : IConsumer<UpdateKontakteintragCommand>
{
    private readonly IKontakteintraegeDomainRepository kontakteintragRepository;

    public UpdateKontakteintragCommandConsumer(IKontakteintraegeDomainRepository kontakteintragRepository)
        => this.kontakteintragRepository = kontakteintragRepository;

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<UpdateKontakteintragCommand> context)
    {
        var kontakteintrag = kontakteintragRepository.Get(context.Message.Id);
```

No the "context.Message.Id" is 0000-0000 ... but in the unit test it is definitly set. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea, is it only when running multiple tests in parallel?

Comment: The tests are running not in parallel. Another working unit test looks similar. I use MassTransit 7.2.2. Older version like 7.1.6 has the same problem.

Comment: I'd try to understand why the working unit test works, and why this one fails.

Comment: I figured out the actual problem: This only occurs in the TestHarness Setup. The normal mediator request/response mechanism works fine: If having a [DataContract] attribute the test harness fails as described above:    
[DataContract(Name = "KontakteintragAktualisieren")]
    public record UpdateKontakteintragCommand : ApplicationCommandRequest
    {
        public string Bemerkung { get; init; }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        // TODO: Fallaktenzuordnungsdatum
    }
After removing the [DataContract] it works again